# What are the artifacts in the Waverider timeship?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

DC Comics [posted](https://www.instagram.com/p/BAxTX5IuUHH/) a message on Instagram saying that the set decorators of Legends of Tomorrow have placed easter eggs that reference DC properties.

[image: Legends of Tomorrow - Easter Eggs]

I am able to see a few

- Old Red Tornado helmet on the table
- Pied Piper's flute
- Sgt. Rock helmet

On Instagram the comments also make mention of

- Orion's helmet; other say it's closer to S.T.R.I.P.E. Is either true?
- Green lantern ring/lantern (I don't see this though)

What other DC properties are referenced in this photo (and where are they)?

Comment: The lantern is on a shelf at the back of the room.

Comment: Is it significant that the lady's right hand is exposed but the left hand is hidden?

Comment: It is not Orion's helmet in any way: lot different, Orion never got a closed one, and it totally miss the small, iconic side wings. But speaking of iconics things, it's pretty obvious where the confusion came from: the guy's arms and hands position are exactly those of Orion. Probably unwillingly :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already identified:

1. **Sgt. Rock's helmet** (on the first person from the left)
2. **Pied Piper's flute** (being played by the person in the middle with the leather trench coat)
3. Ma Hunkel's **Old Red Tornado helmet** (on the table at the extreme left of the photo)

## We also have...

4. A **lantern from Green Lantern Corps** on the top shelf at the back of the room:

[image]

5. The helmet worn by the individual at the right seems to be the DCAU-version of **S.T.R.I.P.E.'s helmet** (notice the two circles on top):

[image]

6. The individual at the right wearing S.T.R.I.P.E.'s helmet is miming **Orion's trademark stance**:

[image]

7. On the bottom shelf at the back, we see **Pandora's skull**:

[image]

8. On the table in the foreground, we see **the lost scrolls of Herculaneum**, magical items found in the DC universe.

Comment: Rorschach's trenchcoat seems like a stretch; unless I'm very much mistaken that's Arthur Darvill, and the coat is part of his regular costume

Comment: @JasonBaker : Definitely Darvill, but I thought his regular coat wasn't leather and was a different shade.  But the filter on this photo could just be playing tricks with my eyes. :-)

Comment: Hm, I suppose it could be a different coat. Hard to be sure with the lighting though

Answer (score 0):

That *may* be the new Guardian's helmet - Jimmy Olsen is taking on the mantle of Guardian in Supergirl, and the mask in the art looks a bit like that

[image]

And technically, Rip's coat is an artifact - he got it from Jonah Hex.